# Symfony2 security : get username when refreshing user

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, doctrine-orm

Why the entity provider in it's `refreshUser` method  returns a `user` object having `NULL` as username instead of the actual username ?

```
public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
{
    $class = get_class($user);
    if (!$this->supportsClass($class)) {
        throw new UnsupportedUserException(
            sprintf(
                'Instances of "%s" are not supported.',
                $class
            )
        );
    }
    var_dump($user->getUsername()); // prints NULL 
    die();
    return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
}
```

Comment: print user object. is `id` filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that only the id attribute is **public**. However the username attribute is may be **private**.
And for that, the serialization of the object user makes the username = null.